# useCallback with empty dependencies, then what is passed as callback param?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-lifecycle

I am not very new to React but below code is hard to understand.

```js
const UIContext = React.createContext();
const initialFilter = { ... };

export function UIProvider({ children }) {
  const [queryParams, setQueryParamsBase] = useState(initialFilter);

  const setQueryParams = useCallback((nextQueryParams) => { // <- my problem is here
    setQueryParamsBase((prevQueryParams) => {
      ... // some operations
      return nextQueryParams;
    });
  }, []);
  
  const value = {
    queryParams,
    setQueryParamsBase,
    setQueryParams,
  };

  return (
    <UIContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </UIContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I know `useCallback` but in the above code a variable called `nextQueryParams` is passed as a parameter of the callback.

What is that `nextQueryParams`? The variable name sounds like related to query params, however I couldn't find what is passed as a parameter to the callback from React documentation.

Please help me if anyone knows this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useCallback` just takes *a function*. Literally just a plain old function. It doesn't take a special function that has pre-defined arguments or anything.

So `setQueryParams` is passed to the `UIContext.Provider` component through the `value` object prop. And inside that component it may use that function while passing an argument, like so `setQueryParams(someValue)`. That `someValue` will become the `nextQueryParams` argument in the function inside `useCallback`.

Comment: Thanks Jayce! I just confirmed that. Why it's not in React document though?

Comment: @yash well I mean it does. It says that you pass in a callback (i.e. some function) and get a memoized version back. I mean it doesn't _specifically_ say "this isn't a special function by the way, just any function you want", but why would it haha. Docs usually specify what things ARE, not what they AREN'T. If it took in a special function, *then* the docs would mention it. So it's safe to assume it isn't.

Comment: It makes me sense. Thanks for your explanation!